# What's the problem with this state province crash?

Tags: error, 4.7, geocoding, google

I migrated at the weekend from 4.6.22 to 4.7.19 and all went smoothly. But now users get the following problem when updating a contact's address. They get 'Unable to reach network' but looking in ConfigandLog I see this line prior to the fatal error:    /home/rsvpadmi/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Google.php(87): CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Core_DAO_StateProvince", "null")

I 'fixed' the problem by switching off Google maps in 'Mapping and Geocoding'. In fact, maps were being displayed OK but users just couldn't update an address.
Anyone have any clues as to what the problem is?

Comment: Paging @ginkgomzd - Is this the problem you were describing at the sprint in St. Louis?  Andy - you might want to upgrade to 4.7.20, this might be a bug that was fixed.  It also sounds similar to CRM-20581, though I doubt it's the same - but that WAS fixed in 4.7.20.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds consistent with hitting a rate limit in Google Maps API.

If so, the fix would be to disable geocoding (as you've done) or to configure a valid API key associated with payment details so Google can bill you for geocoding.

I recently observed similar behaviour when a client was viewing large numbers of contacts in a proximity smart group - possibly this triggered a mass lookup of contacts who lacked geographic co-ordinates.

Your CiviCRM debug log may have more information.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I did try an API but maybe picked the wrong one from Google's confusing list.  I guess the one I need is the 'Google Static Maps API' ?

Comment: I added the 'Google Static Maps API' for mapping (using Google) and selected 'Open Street Mapping' for Geo Coding, which has done the trick.